# How to select input tag when followed by span tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to select an `input` tag when it is followed by `span` :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text"/>
<span>
    ...
</span>
```

**CSS :**

```
input [followed span] {
    padding:5px; (set input padding, only when followed by span)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by target?

Comment: @AnandG target the input tag in css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use + selector to Selects all `<span>` elements that are placed immediately after `<input>` elements

```css
input + span {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<span>test</span>
```

---

If you want to select `<input>` that is placed before `<span>`. this is not doable in css since,

> Cascading Style Sheets : A cascade is like a waterfall, there’s no
>   backward motion. So, naturally, there is no previous sibling selector
>   in CSS.

Read more https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/previous-sibling-css-selector/

---

what you can try is `.prev()` of jQuery..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').prev().css('background','yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<span>test</span>
```

For more info about `.prev()`  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_prev.asp

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: i want to select input when followed by span. Is this doable in css?

Comment: @simpleguy please see my updated answer and hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This will return content in span tag but uh need to specify at which input tag you're pointing either by using class or id for exact result.

```
$("input").closest("span").html()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do Adjacent Sibling Selector using:

```
input + span {  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

or you can do General Sibling Selector using:

```
input ~ span {  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Here is more info:  http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/10-handy-css-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not offer "before" selectors. The only solution would be to add a class to each element and style it or do it with jQUery like this:

```
.inputs_before_span {
color: #0cc;
}

$('span').prev('span').addClass('inputs_before_span')
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Use this css:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

input {
    padding-left: 48px;
}

.wrapper span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="url" placeholder="e.g. www.google.com" />
    <span>http://</span>    
</div>
```

Source: [Display span over input with HTML+CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653207/display-span-over-input-with-htmlcss)